# How do you register a 'click' event on (protip) tooltip content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using http://protip.rocks/ for it's tooltips but I'm having a problem.

So I have :

```
<span class="tooltip_templates">
            <span id="tooltip_content_{TAB_LOOP.ITEM_LOOP.ITEM_ID}">
            <!-- BEGIN ITEM_LOOP.CHILD_ITEM_LOOP -->
            <!-- IF TAB_LOOP.ITEM_LOOP.ITEM_ID == TAB_LOOP.ITEM_LOOP.CHILD_ITEM_LOOP.P_ID -->
            <a href ="#"><img class = 'hide' src ="{T_IMAGES_PATH}custom_avatars/item_thumbnails/{TAB_LOOP.ITEM_LOOP.CHILD_ITEM_LOOP.C_ID}.png" title ="{TAB_LOOP.ITEM_LOOP.ITEM_NAME}" id ="{TAB_LOOP.ITEM_LOOP.CHILD_ITEM_LOOP.C_ID}"/></a>
            <!-- ENDIF -->
            <!-- END ITEM_LOOP.CHILD_ITEM_LOOP -->
             <a href = "#"><img class = 'hide' src ="{T_IMAGES_PATH}custom_avatars/item_thumbnails/{TAB_LOOP.ITEM_LOOP.ITEM_ID}.png" title ="{TAB_LOOP.ITEM_LOOP.ITEM_NAME}" id ="{TAB_LOOP.ITEM_LOOP.ITEM_ID}" /></a>
            </span>
          </span>
```

and

```
 $( ".tooltip_templates img" ).click(function() {
      alert("ok"); 
  });`
```

the event doesn't fire here, so I checked the source of the page and saw

[image]

So it looks like the content was moved to protip-content however, changing the click function's class to .protip-content doesn't fire the event either. Any ideas?

I tried to do some testing here by attaching an alert to all **image** clicks and as you can see the event isnt called when clicking the image inside of the tooltip..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. I think the reason why your DOM Elements [.tooltip_templates img] didn't call the event because it hadn't been called in the DOM after $(document).ready(). You need to attach and fire those events by either using [.on] or [.delegate]:

References:

[on] = http://api.jquery.com/on/

[delegate] = http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

```
$('.tooltip_templates img').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('here');
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle for a sample reference:
http://jsfiddle.net/qrgphhu6/